# Micro SD for Raspberry PI 2 B

Tags: raspberry-pi, microsd

I'm going to buy a Raspberry PI 2 B and install osmc on it.
I'm wondering which type (r/w speed) of Micro SD I should buy and which size (8, 16 ,32 go).
My movies, pictures, etc are stored on an Nas and the Raspberry will be wired on the same LAN.

I will try to be more precise :
I will only stream to the raspberry from my NAS. Some movie than well be stream can be 20go in size.
The purpose of the Mirco SD will be to allow OSMC to run as smoothly as possible on the Raspberry 2B.

Comment: I think you should make a judgement on what size to buy on your own accord. If you plan on storing movies on the PI, then 32/64Gb makes sense. Otherwize, if you plan on streaming media to it, 8 should be fine. In addition, there is little fluxuation between speeds of high end MicroSD cards (as seen here:http://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/fastest-microsd-cards), so you should just choose one from a brand you trust.

Comment: What's your budget? That's one of the most important factors here since MicroSDs aren't too complex.

Comment: @Adam I have a budget of 100€ for the sd card alone but if I can spend less the better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

I ended up buying a SanDisk extreme plus micro SDHC 16 GB (20€).
OSMC runs more than smoothly on it.

16 GB seems to be a good size. OSMC takes less than 300 MB but the metadata, thumbnails, artworks and add-ons are also stored on the SD card.
I'm able to play my heaviest movies (20 GB) through NFS without issue.

Any card with the same R/W speed should do the trick.